# Switch with cases with casting

Tags: ios, swift

I want to do this with a switch:

```
 protocol TestProtocol {}

 class A: TestProtocol {}
 class B: TestProtocol {}

 var randomObject: TestProtocol

 if let classAObj = randomObject as? A {
 } else if let classBObj = randomObject as? B {}
```

I want something like this:

```
switch randomObject {
    case let classAObj = randomObject as? A:
         ...
    case let classBObj = randomObject as? B:
         ....
     default:
         fatalError("not implemented")
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sure you can:

```
switch randomObject {
case let classAObj as A:
    // Here `classAObj` has type `A`.
    // ...
case let classBObj as B:
    // Here `classBObj` has type `B`.
    // ...
default:
    fatalError("not implemented")
}
```

In a pattern matching expression it is `as`, not `as?`,
and `= randomObject` is not needed, the value to match is given
right after the `switch` keyword.

And just for the sake of completeness: Pattern matching with
`case let` *can* also be used in if-statements (or while/for-statements):

```
if case let classAObj as A = randomObject {

} else if case let classBObj as B = randomObject {

}
```

However in this case there would be no reason to do so.

Comment: I was wondering if using case is A/ case is B will be less expensive?

Comment: @koropok: I doubt that it makes a difference. And usually you want the downcasted object, then you need `as` anyway.